# How can I update values in Prisma using Node.js framework and session data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma

I am trying to update some values using Prisma Schema and Nodejs as a framework but i cant seem to update the values I have generated the Prisma Model which is

```
model Account_info {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username String?
  password String?
  email String?
  first_name String?
  last_name String?
  contact_number String?
  address String?          
  @@unique([username,password])
  }
```

and the JS Code is :

```
app.post("/updated_data" ,async function(req,res){
        const login_data = await prisma.account_info.update({
         data:{
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            contact_number : req.body.phone,
            address : req.body.address
        },
        where:{
            username : req.session.username,
            password : req.session.password
        },
        })
    })
```

The Error Message is shown below

Unknown arg username in where.username for type Account_infoWhereUniqueInput. Available args:

type Account_infoWhereUniqueInput {
id?: String
username_password?: Account_infoUsernamePasswordCompoundUniqueInput
}